# how to show markers in google map ,latitude and longitude obtained from xml url after parsing in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist, google-maps-markers

Can anyone please help in finding the solution of the above question

I have parsed my webservice and saved the latitude and longitude obtained in an arraylist.
I want to show markers in my map according to the latitude and longitude saved in the array list till that array list is empty.

If i have 5 set of latitudes and longitudes in my array list i want to show 5 markers in my map?

Please help me. this is my 3rd qn and i couldn't find any relevant answers except some voting down.
Please help me out!!!

Comment: Hay! you should better do search before posting a question. there are lot of posts about this. Have a look at [this post](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/04/google-map-example-in-android-with-info.html)

Comment: Often that means the question has already been asked elsewhere or there is easy to find documentation about the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well have you gone [though the tutorials](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=E20A1B43E7276907502275B952877EDF?recipeId=2308&recipeFrom=ViewTOC) ?

Your code should look like this after following the linked tutorial

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) { 
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(arrayList.get(i).latitude * 1E6, arrayList.get(i).longitude * 1E6);
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "Point" + i, null);
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(overlayItem);
}
mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
mapView.invalidate();
```